# How to force `Xcode-generated header` ... in a Swift Project (Call Swift from Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Xcode does not generate this `-Swift.h` header file when the project is a Swift project. The documentation says:

> When you import Swift code into Objective-C, you rely on an
>   Xcode-generated header file to expose those files to Objective-C. This 
>   automatically generated file is an Objective-C header that declares
>   the Swift interfaces in your target. It can be thought of as an
>   umbrella header for your Swift code. The name of this header is your
>   product module name followed by adding "-Swift.h".

If I try to include the `-Swift.h` file anyway, it says `file not found`.
I've been able to generate this file before in an Objective-C project.
But I want to call Swift from Objective-C, in a Swift project.

How do I call Swift from Obj-C in a Swift project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If the Objective-C file in which you import `*-Swift.h` is in the same Swift target that contains the Swift code you are trying to use in Objective-C, you should have no trouble importing it.  To make sure you are using the correct name, check the `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` under `Build Settings`.  If the target is a framework,  you may need to import the `-Swift.h` header a little differently:

`#import "YourFrameworkModuleName/YourFrameworkModuleName-Swift`.h"

whereas in an application target you would just do

```
#import "YourAppModuleName-Swift.h"
```

This is something I found from my experience.

Comment: Thank you the .h imports great now but the swift code is not reading and I did add @objc. This is a framework